# javascript for Array how many and min

Tags: adobe, acrobat

I am trying to create a form in Acrobat. I want it to do some calculations. I got almost all of them done aside from 2.

1. I have an array of cells DF1 to DF78 so I need a calculation script that will give me the minimum value in that array not counting the blank ones.
2. In the same array of cells DF1 to DF78 I need a calculation script to find how many fields in that array have value and bring me up the number.

I already tried using the min option on the acrobat DC and selecting the fields. Ii want to look at DF1 to DF78. However, it always shows 0 because it's counting the empty fields as well.

I tried looking online, but all the scripts that they show are very confusing. I can't find where to put the array in there.

I wish I had a script to put it in here... sorry.

I have fields DF1 to DF78 so a total of 78 fields, and I need to find the minimum value in that array not including the fields that are blank.

Another script for the same fields DF1 to DF78 needs to count how many of the fields actually have data ex: DF1, DF2, DF3 had data on it and the rest are empty so it should display the number 3 because 3 of the 78 fields have data in them.

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work... Add it to the calculate action of a new hidden field you want the numbers to show up. Fix the names on the last two lines first.

```
 valueArray = [];
 for (var i = 1; i <= 78 ; i++) {
      //Get the fieldvalue by assembling the name with the prefix and the number increment
      var fieldVal = this.getField("DF"+i).value;
      //Acrobat field values are never null. The value of a blank field is an empty string 
      if (fieldVal != "") {
           //Add non-empty field values to an Array.
           valueArray.push(fieldValue);
      }
 }
 // Get the minimum value in the array.
 var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, valueArray);
 // Get the number of non-blank fields.
 var nonBlankFields = valueArray.length;

 this.getField("RESULT FOR YOUR 1st QUESTION FIELD NAME HERE").value = minValue;
 this.getField("RESULT FOR YOUR 2nd QUESTION FIELD NAME HERE").value = nonBlankFields;
```

Comment: i keep getting this error message, the  // Get the number of non-blank fields. keeps highlighted and syntax error 12 at line13

Comment: Apparently, Acrobat JavaScript doesn't like the "..." in the min method. I adjusted the code in the minValue line to something that I've actually tested in Acrobat.